# Div is on the text (p)

Tags: css, html, image

I have to put a div containing some images flush left, and soon after a title with a text. Side by side.

But I'm not getting.

The text is getting underneath the images.
See the website:
http://www.amsdarquitetura.com.br/Project/Details?ProjectID=100

I like to put side by side (images and text)

Comment: "need a div (with pictures) is aligned" confusing.

Comment: I'm sorry, I rephrased the question.

Answer (score 0):

Make both the text and image block elements:

```
img, p {
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying width on the two floated divs such that they add up to less than 100%.

Comment: I can not set a size for the photos vary in size and the text should fit.

The pictures can have a maximum width of 460px (1px by 460px)

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
width:50%;
```

on the `.left` class (*unless you use it elsewhere*)

---

Alternatively you can set a class for each div and set a different width for each one.

The important thing is that the sum of those two does not exceed the width of their parent (*`#content`*).

Comment: Remained the same. The picture is still above the text.

Comment: Try setting the with to something like 40% and let us know what happens.

Comment: @Riderman, updated answer (*i see that you use the `.left` class nested in other `.left` elements.*). Use the second option and add a class in each div and set the widths through those.

Comment: I can not set a size for the photos vary in size and the text should fit.

The pictures can have a maximum width of 460px (1px by 460px)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you'll be able to pull the light gray `<span>` away from the image, as it's part of the image's parent container.

Adding `float:left; width:200px` to your `<div class=left>` container brought everything up to the right of the image...sans the gray `<span>` element.

Is it possible for you to refactor the code - moving that `<span>` into `<div class="left">`?